# Twitter Sentiment Analysis Using R and Tableau

Tags: r, tableau-api

I am working on a twitter sentiment analysis for which I have used R to run the   sentiment for me. I am referring to very helpful article from Bora Beran here:

[Sentiment Analysis](https://boraberan.wordpress.com/2013/12/24/sentiment-analysis-in-tableau-with-r/)

I was successfully able to run the R script yesterday using R server and even the sentiments worked fine. But today the same script shows the error as `"could not find classify_polarity()`.

Please note I have downloaded the sentiment package from archive in R and it is working fine in R Studio. Similarly I have checked the connection in Tableau and it shows connection successfully.
Made some changes to the script as :

```
SCRIPT_STR('library(sentiment);
classify_polarity(.arg1,algorithm=”bayes”,verbose=TRUE)[,4]',
ATTR([Status Text]))
```

The error I get is written down below and this [png file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EGe4.png) shows it in Tableau. Please advice what could be the  possible issue.

```
Error in base::parse(text= .cmd): 
<text>:2:36: unexpected input 1: library(sentiment);
2: classify_polarity(.arg1,algorithm= �^
```

Comment: Given the � symbol could it be that the issue is caused by the double quotation marks? (Not an expert on R)